# Strong(Completed) Induction Proof Explanation of Solution

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

Can someone please give a bit more elaborations on this given solution already? Sorry. English is not my first language. if this is not the place to ask question like this, please let me know if there is better webpage for this. Thank you and apologize in advance. 
`

Question:
    Use strong induction to show that every positive integer n can be written as a sum of distinct powers of two, that is, as a sum of the integers s 2^0= 1, 2^1=2, 2^2=4, .... so on.

`
Given solution:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdaVR.jpg)

This explains very well already, but I want to learn the MATH language to 100% know how to use MATH terms to communicate,

so someone please have a "better" way to say "which simply increases the exponent of each power of two by 1" 
(highlighted in the uploaded picture).

As the previous sentence, " We can then multiply this sum by 2," I believe this sum is  (k + 1)/2 . If so, when multiply (k + 1)/2) *2 = (k + 1). then, having(k +1) means "increases the exponent of each power of two by 1"?. How so? Thank you again!

Ps: Sorry being so picky. As the question state: "every positive integer n can be written as a sum of distinct powers of two," Does 1 count ? because it is not a **sum** of of distinct powers of two. While 2^0=1, but in order to to have a sum, other positive integer(formed by distinct powers of 2) need to be added; in this case is 0, however, we can't get a 0 from any distinct powers of 2. 2^0=1 already. then 1+1 is 2, which means not every positive integer n can be written as a sum of distinct powers of 2.(Only for the positive integer n greater or equal to 2.